# Is Stack Overflow a suitable place for machine learning questions?

Tags: discussion

Sometimes in the Stack Overflow we encounter with questions that are purely related to machine learning. I think Cross Validated is the correct place for such questions. But, do you think Stack Overflow can also contain such questions?

Comment: Ask the Stack Overflow community. We can't say anything useful about this.

Comment: [Do pure “machine learning” questions belong to Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291009/4493879)

Comment: Thanks. I was unaware that the Stack Overflow has its own Meta section.

Comment: "If you want to use this tag for a question not directly concerning implementation, then consider posting on Computer Science, Cross Validated or Data Science instead. Otherwise you're probably off-topic." - [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info)

Answer (score 3):

[Artificial Intelligence](https://ai.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchange (currently in Beta) seems to accept machine learning questions.

They have a [machine-learning](/questions/tagged/machine-learning) [tag](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning?sort=newest) with 99 questions.

> For questions about machine learning (ml) and the related concepts with respect to AI.

Comment: Sounds like promoting of a beta site!